# Create a new <td> if it exceeds a certain width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC site, I have a these lines of code:

```
<h2>@Model.Question</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Result", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                @foreach (string answer in Model.Answers)
                {
                    <td><input type="radio" name="answer" value="@answer" /><span>@answer</span></td>
                }
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="footer">
            <input class="btn btn-success" direction="false" type="submit" name="Back" value="Back" />
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" />
        </div>
    }
```

(Ignore the currently poorly implement first button in the footer)

The `<input type="radio...` returns the same amount of radio buttons as answers from a database. My problem is that for one question, there are a lot of answers and it starts making the page scroll sideways, as shown in the image below[image]

What I want to happen is for the radio buttons to start on a new line, possibly in another `<td>`, when it starts to go too far sideways. Possibly done when it hits the border of a surrounding div I could create? Or when it exceeds a certain pixel width? I am not quite sure how to approach this at all. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this question about ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: unless you render the page on your server, using the same engine your user's browser does, "width" is a meaningless concept. you'd need to detect how bigt the user's browser window is, how big the div is on screen, calculate the width of your text using the user's font settings, blah blah blah. the only thing you can EASILY calculate on the server is the number of characters in your string, which is essentially useless unless you're using a fixed-width font.

Comment: With that many options you might consider a different element. Maybe a drop down box.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? If so, this might be easier to accomplish using div tags instead. Would you be open to an approach using `div`s instead of of a table?

Comment: @jcubic I included that because this whole project is using MVC.

Comment: @MarcB would it be possible to make sure that the td element doesn't exceed an outer div, then?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using tables for your job, it is better to use DIV with fixed width (or percentage width) and floating them left so they stick together in one line. When there will be too much elements for one line, they will automatically jump to a new line. This will also work if you will change width of your browser.

CSS part:

```
.elements {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.elements:before,
.elements:after{
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.elements:after {
  clear: both;
}

.element {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

HTML Part:

```
<div class="elements">
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="" /> Radio
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4xvdcw9b/2/

Comment: This theory seems like it could work out well, so thank you.

Comment: Please mark as correct answer if it does the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If using table is not necessary you can try this approach:

```
<ul>
                    @foreach (string answer in Model.Answers)
                    {
                        <li><input type="radio" name="answer" value="@answer" /><span>@answer</span></li>
                    }
            </ul>
```

with this styles:

```
ul
{
   max-width:300px;
list-style-type: none;
}

li
{
   display: inline; 
}
```